# Optimize circle animation

Tags: jquery, css, animation, fullpage.js

I have a circle animation, where circles are expanding over some time. You can see the animation here: https://rimildeyjsr.github.io/spotify-circle-animation/

The animation went run for a long time is slowing down the website considerably - you can literally see the frames drop and the scrolling animation (using fullPage.js) lags throughout the screen.

To optimise the animation, I have tried out the following:

- **Remove the circle divs from the page when it reaches the end of its animation** - this doesn't seem to help too much because on scrolling to the next pages I can still see the initial circles expanding with pixelation.
- **Limit the size of the `divs`** - I have tried changing the animation
  from `scale(100.0,100.0)` to `scale(50.0,50.0)` on 100%, which slows
  expansion of the circles. I have tried changing the initial size from
  `1000px` to `500px`, this also slows down the expansion of the circles. Both these solutions have no effect on optimisation, the animation still slows down the website.
- **Start and stop the animation on scrolling to every section** - Since I
  am using fullPage.js this is possible using the `afterLoad` and
  `onLeave` callbacks. Only problem being I don't know how to stop the animation.

Here is my code:

CSS:

```
html,body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-color: #24ccdf;
}

.initial-div {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
    transform: scale(0);
}

.position-div{
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: none;
}

.animate {
    -webkit-animation: expand 2500s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes expand {
    0%{
        -webkit-transform: scale(0,0);
    }

    100%{
        -webkit-transform: scale(100.0,100.0);
        display: none;
    }
}
```

jQuery:

```
var animationEnd = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';

        function makeDiv(color){
            var divsize = 1000;
            //$('body').css({'background-color':bgColor});
            $newdiv = $('<div/>').addClass('initial-div').css({
                'background-color': color
            });

            var posx = (Math.random() * ($('.section').width()) - (divsize / 2)).toFixed();
            var posy = (Math.random() * ($('.section').height()) - (divsize / 2)).toFixed();

            $newdiv.addClass('position-div').css({
                'left':posx+'px',
                'top':posy+'px'
            }).appendTo("#fullpage").addClass('animate').css({'display':'block'}).one(animationEnd,function(){
                $(this).remove();
            });
        }

 $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#fullpage').fullpage({
                anchors: ['home','about','projects','blog','contact'],
                fixedElements: '#toggle,#overlay',
                afterLoad : function(anchorLink,index) {
                    if(index == 1 || anchorLink == 'home'){
                        circleAnimation();
                    }
                     else if(index == 2 || anchorLink == 'about'){
                        $('#section2 h1').addClass('come-in').one(animationEnd,function(){
                            $('#section2 h3').addClass('come-in').one(animationEnd,function(){
                                $('#section2 p').addClass('come-in');
                            });
                        });
                    }
                }
            });

            function circleAnimation(){
                var colorArray = ['#11256c','#24ccdf'];
                var i= 0,flag=0;
                var color = colorArray[i];
                setInterval(function(){
                    flag++;
                    makeDiv(color);
                    if (flag == 15){
                        color = colorArray[i];
                        i++;
                        if (i == 2) {
                            i = 0;
                        }
                        flag=0;
                    }
                },2000);
            }

        });
```

Any help, hints or pointers are sincerely appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before suggesting a solution, I need to know what your expectations are:

- Each animation now lasts for 2500s which is more than 40 minutes. Is this your intention or should it last 2500ms?
- Each animation starts at the top of the page making the edges at the bottom of the page very ugly. Is this intentional or should circles start at a random position of the page?

Furthermore, display:none cannot be animated.

I have made a [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/beekvang/8y72cdu1/) for you to check. Changes made:

```
.animate {
  -webkit-animation: expand 250s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes expand {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
}
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: sorry for so many edits. 2500s is just to slow down the expansion, instead of that time property if there is any way to slow down, I am ready to embrace that. Also, the circles should start at random positions, I don't want it to expand beyond the screen which as you mentioned is leading to ugly edges. My only expectation is that the circles start and expand, and when they cover about  more than half the screen, the color inverts and the animation starts over again.

Comment: I hope  i clearly communicated what I want from the animation

Comment: You can play a little with the settings. Probably expand 40s is already good enough.

Comment: Thanks that has optimized my solution a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Velocity.js](http://velocityjs.org/) it was designed to optimize animations and to reduce load.

Check "Performance" in the top of the site to view an example

http://velocityjs.org/

Comment: its to be used with $.animate(), I don't have any animate functions in my code